# How to run python script from launch file

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file, with following:

```
 <!-- Launch Gazebo -->   
 <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/turtlebot_world.launch"> </include>
 <!-- Launch AMCL -->  
 <include file="$(find my_package)/launch/my_amcl.launch">    </include>
 <!-- Launch Move base -->  
 <!-- Launch Rviz -->
```

Inside this launch file I want to also run a python script navigate.py located in my_package/scripts.
I have try `<include file="$(find my_package)/scripts/navigate.py">  </include>`
but it doesn't works. Is there a way to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339930/how-to-run-python-script-from-launch-file/) by [kiko453](https://answers.ros.org/users/45196/kiko453/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked and answered before: https://answers.ros.org/question/229841/how-launch-a-python-script-with-roslaunch/

---

Originally posted by [fexner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26760/fexner/) with karma: 221 on 2019-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiko453](https://answers.ros.org/users/45196/kiko453/) on 2019-12-14**:
this is not the same. I tried that, but didn't work.
SO I've tried

```
  <node pkg="my_package" name="navigate.py" type="navigate.py" output="screen"> 
  </node>
```

but it didn't work

**Comment by [fexner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26760/fexner/) on 2019-12-16**:
Did you make your script executable? `navigate.py` has to be an executable script. See the [example python node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.The_Code) for details

**Comment by [kiko453](https://answers.ros.org/users/45196/kiko453/) on 2020-01-24**:
working now, thanks.